# Is it possible to run run a kernel written in C on github-pages with WebAssembly?

Tags: c, kernel, webassembly, osdev

I have a custom kernel written in C, but I want people to be able to play around with it(ie with Github Pages or something similar) when they visit my Github repo. Is there a way for me to deploy this with wasm(ie with a Github Action) so people can use the kernel in a web browser after clicking on a link?

Comment: Yes. You'll probably also want to make a simple webpage to put around your compiled webassembly, tho, so people can actually interact with it.

Comment: Sorry, if you have the time, could you quickly explain how one would go about running a qemu-run kernel in wasm, or link a resource to learn from?